# Enter data in web form, output to a new page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, web

I am using a simple `<form>` to collect data from a user.  The user clicks a simple button to enter the data: `<input type="submit" name="cmd" value="OK">`.  Currently the application does a simple post back, displays the filled in form, and under the form, displays the results.

The users now want the results to go to another page.  Basically they want to change a variable and compare the results in different tabs.  My first proposal was to keep the post back and then add a hyperlink using `target="_blank"` to push the results to a different tab but they do not like the two-clicks: OK button then hyperlink.

Is it possible to send the results of a form input to another page?

I am programming in C# using ASP.NET.

Comment: You should store both of the data to compare with each other, this will be more professional. You can store data in many different ways: cookies, sessions, static datas, writing to a text file, save to a database, etc. Once you store it, you can render the comparison in a good looking one page.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by postbackurl property in c#. thus helps you to access your previous page controls and there output on next page. you can also do this by using hidden field and post or get method. both options are good and reliable.
[reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.postbackurl%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that you are using ASP.Net, I would recommend you utilise the power of the code-behind process. One option that you can do in addition to the above responses is use a `QueryString` in your `URL` as you do a re-direct if that is available to you as a requirement. 
 Example 1. Use a ASP `Button`

```
protected void btnOriginalPage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string url = "NextPageViewer.aspx?result=" + resultText;

    //You can use JavaScript to perform the re-direct
    string cmd = "window.open('" + url + "', '_blank', 'height=500,width=900);";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "newWindow", cmd, true);

    //or you can use this - which ever you choose
    Response.Redirect(url);
}

///On the next page - the one you have been redirected to, perform the following
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //extract the query string and use it as you please
    int result = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["resultText"]);
}
```

Example 2. Use a `Session` variable and store your dataset/result in an user defined object or `DTO` - this is just a class with a bunch of `setter`s and `getter`s
Perform the click event on the ASP button except this time you would do something like this:

```
protected void btnOriginalPage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ObjectWithInfo.Result = result;

    Session["friendlyName"] = ObjectWithInfo;

    Response.Redirect("NextPageViewer.aspx");
}

    //On the next page - the one you have been redirected to, perform the following
//The good thing with Session variables is that you can access the session almost anywhere in you application allowing your users to perform the comparison they require.
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //extract the data from the object to use
        int result = ((ObjectWithInfo)(Session["friendlyName"])).Result;
    }
```